# Images in relative path not loading Cordova android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, whitelist

Images are in path

> C:\Users\username\Source\Repos\mobile-app\resources\icons\android

**config.xml**

```
<platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="resources/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="resources/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="resources/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
</platform>
```

Have the below code included

```
  <access origin="*" />
```

Please let me know if any further information is needed. It loads default images into the application

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your ionic cli with `npm install -g ionic`, then try to regenerate icons with `ionic resources --icon`.

1. Put your images in the ./resources directory, named splash or icon.
2. Accepted file types are .png, .ai, and .psd.
3. Icons should be 192x192 px without rounded corners.

Hope it helps.